# Adding New Row of Custom TinyMCE

Tags: tinymce, wp-editor

I have added some custom tinymce to the WP editor using the following code:

PHP

```
add_action( 'init', 'my_theme_buttons' );
function my_theme_buttons() {
add_filter("mce_external_plugins", "my_theme_add_buttons");
add_filter('mce_buttons', 'my_theme_register_buttons');
}   
function my_theme_add_buttons($plugin_array) {
$plugin_array['buttons'] = get_template_directory_uri() . '/editor-buttons/buttons-plugin.js';
return $plugin_array;
}
function my_theme_register_buttons($buttons) {
array_push( $buttons, 'arrowicon' ); // &etc for each icon... name from buttons-plugin.js
return $buttons;
}
```

Javascript

```
(function() {
tinymce.create('tinymce.plugins.buttons', {
        init : function(ed, url) {

        ed.addCommand('arrowicon', function() {

            return_text = '[arrow-icon]';
            ed.execCommand('mceInsertContent', 0, return_text);
        });

        // &etc for each icon...            

        ed.addButton('arrowicon', {
            title : 'Arrow Icon',
            cmd : 'arrowicon',
            image : url + '/arrow-right.png'
        });

        // &etc for each icon...            
 },

  createControl : function(n, cm) {
        return null;
    },

});

// Register plugin
tinymce.PluginManager.add('buttons', tinymce.plugins.buttons);
})();
```

Everything works fine but I want to display my custom icons in the second row of the wp-editor so that they can be toggled with the "kitchen sink" button (preferably in the third row). Right now they are displayed like so:

[image: display in wordpress editor]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to hook the filter to `mce_buttons_2` instead of `mce_buttons`

```
add_filter('mce_buttons_2', 'my_theme_register_buttons');
```

In this way the buttons will appear on the second row.

Comment: Great thanks! I actually ended up using `add_filter('mce_buttons_3', 'my_theme_register_buttons');` To get it on the third row.